How can I set a maximum number of errors in tsc?
I have a legacy project we are trying to move over to typescript.  tsc --noEmit finds 85 errors and exits 2.
I want to do like tsc --noEmit --maxErrors=85 and have it exit 0.  Then as we fix errors, we can lower the maxErrors until we get it down to 0.
You can do this with eslint.
There doesn't seem to be a cli option for this.
yarn tsc --version says Version 4.8.4
Thought about doing some sort of pipe and grep hack. I'm using zsh but I'm apparently not having a good brain day because I can't figure out how to capture where it says Found 82 errors in 15 files..  Doesn't seem to be in stdout or stderr.  I tried yarn tsc --noEmit | grep -i "errors in" and it didn't catch anything.

I found a tool which solved exactly the problem.
https://phenomnomnominal.github.io/betterer/docs/introduction
They have also a typescript plugin ready to go and it works fine for me.
When you include it in your CI, you are able to deny code which create new errors.

Ok I figured out a workaround.  If you pass --pretty to tsc, then you can grep the output like normal.
yarn tsc --noEmit --pretty | grep -i "Found \d* errors" | awk '{print $2}' | ./tsc_hack.sh
In tsc_hack.sh you can do something like
MAX_ERRORS=82
read -r ERRORS

if [ $ERRORS -gt $MAX_ERRORS ]; then
  echo "Max errors: $MAX_ERRORS. Found: $ERRORS";
  exit 1
fi

echo "Found $ERRORS errors out of maximum $MAX_ERRORS. OK"

This is hideous. I might just ignore the files that have problems instead.
